# Equivalent of c\c++ compiler directives in Julia

Tags: julia, compiler-directives

using compiler directives like

```
#if A
some instructions 
#elseif B
some instructions
#end
```

In C\C++ language, one can tell the compiler to ignore some parts of code under some conditions. I`m curious about to know if there is an equivalent of this feature in Julia language.

Answer (score 7):

[`@static`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/base/#Base.@static) is what you're looking for.

```
@static if A
  some instructions
elseif B
  some instructions
end
```

Comment: Cross posting from [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/equivalent-of-c-c-compiler-directives-in-julia/10480).